# Update Quantity of Line Item in all Pending Orders

Tags: commerce, rules

Let me begin by saying this, although I'm not new to Drupal, I am fairly new to getting into hooks and the like, so any amount of guidance is helpful. Also, I know my use case seems strange, but it's one that I need to figure out before I move forward.

My scenario in Commerce: A user specifies a price they want to pay for a product and can add any number of products to their cart. They are not charged initially, but a recurring payment is created with a run date at the end of the month. These products are all related (via Entity Reference) to a specific content type (a Project).

On the second to last day of the month, I need to be able to update ALL of the orders with a specific quantity for each line item.

I need to create a form that the product owner will use that lists all of his or her products (that relate to the specific project they've created) for sale and will give them one single text field per product. They enter the quantity there, and that quantity is applied to every order placed for the product.

The purchaser of the product will have a field in their profile called something like "Max amount per month" that they'll set so that no matter what quantity is entered, they won't pay more than the amount they've specified in their profile.

My thought is to create a Content Type called "Update Order Quantities" that could use a view to show all the products the specific project, and then add a rule to trigger once they click "Update".

I have other pieces I need to figure out along this path, but this is the most important piece right now.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.